# Systemd service does not log output of main script

Tags: systemd, python

I have a systemd unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description = testtesttest
After = network.target

[Service]
Type = simple
ExecStart = /usr/bin/python3.9 -u /home/pi/initialize.py
PIDFile=/home/pi/faulty.pid
User = root
Group = root
Restart = on-failure
RestartSec = 5
TimeoutStartSec = infinity

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

initialize.py:

```
import subprocess
# Pretend like there is some initialization here
s = subprocess.run(['su', 'pi', "-c", "python3.9 -u faulty.py"], cwd="/home/pi", text=True)
# faulty.py is located under /home/pi
```

faulty.py:

```
import os, time
with open("faulty.pid", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(os.getpid()))
print("AAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
time.sleep(60)
raise NameError("Boom")
```

The problem I have is that the output of faulty.py can not be seen using **systemctl status test** or **journalctl -u test**.
However I **can** find it in syslog.
I also tried Type forking instead of simple, did not help.
Also if I manually execute initialize.py, the output of faulty.py is in the terminal.
Replacing

```
s = subprocess.run(['su', 'pi', "-c", "python3.9 -u faulty.py"], cwd="/home/pi", text=True)
```

with

```
s = subprocess.run(["python3.9", "-u", "faulty.py"], cwd="/home/pi", text=True)
```

also produces expected logs.
**UPD:**

```
s = subprocess.run("sudo -u pi bash -c 'python3.9 -u faulty.py'", cwd='/home/pi', text=True, shell=True)
```

Also **works** and changes user. (so sudo is better I guess)
Journalctl log (case Forking):

```
Aug 03 12:35:42 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting testtesttest...
Aug 03 12:35:42 raspberrypi su[52929]: (to pi) root on none
Aug 03 12:35:42 raspberrypi su[52929]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user pi(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Aug 03 12:36:43 raspberrypi systemd[1]: test.service: New main PID 52947 does not exist or is a zombie.
Aug 03 12:36:43 raspberrypi systemd[1]: test.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Aug 03 12:36:43 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start testtesttest.
Aug 03 12:36:48 raspberrypi systemd[1]: test.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Aug 03 12:36:48 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped testtesttest.
```

Journalctl log (case Simple):

```
Aug 03 12:42:29 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started testtesttest.
Aug 03 12:42:29 raspberrypi su[53443]: (to pi) root on none
Aug 03 12:42:29 raspberrypi su[53443]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user pi(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Aug 03 12:43:29 raspberrypi systemd[1]: test.service: Succeeded.
```

Comment: @Panki your first comment is false: _from python subprocess module documentation_ "With the default settings of None, no redirection will occur; the child’s file handles will be inherited from the parent", which means stdout is directed to caller process' stdout. I also mentioned that I **can** find the output in syslog, but not in the log of service itself.

Comment: @Panki `subprocess.check_output` will capture the output into the resulting object, `s` in my case, but this is not what I want, I want redirection. Lastly, preparation requires sudo priviliges, while the faulty.py script does not, so this is exactly how I want it to be

Comment: Sorry I missed the part about syslog. So to clarify: Running `initialize.py` directly produces the expected logging in `stdout`, but not via `systemd` service?

Comment: Yes, running `/usr/bin/python3.9 -u /home/pi/initialize.py` does write aaa... in stdout and after a minute a NameError in stderr

Comment: ugh, I'm also experiencing this. Did you find a resolution?

Comment: Nevermind, `-u` worked for me (and this answer helped push me in the direction of trying: https://serverfault.com/a/909264/88679)